# Rails: repeated ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique when creating objects with Postgres?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm working with a Rails 4 app that needs to create a large number of objects in response to events from another system.  I am getting very frequent `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` errors (caused by `PG::UniqueViolation`) on the primary key column when I call `create!` on one of my models.

I found other answers on SO that suggest rescuing the exception and calling `retry`:

```
begin
  TableName.create!(data: 'here')
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
  if e.message.include? '_pkey' # Only retry primary key violations
    log.warn "Retrying creation: #{e}"
    retry
  else
    raise
  end
end
```

While this seems to help, I am still getting *tons* of `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` errors, for sequential IDs that already exist in the database (log entries abbreviated):

```
WARN -- Retrying creation: PG::UniqueViolation: DETAIL: Key (id)=(3067) already exists.
WARN -- Retrying creation: PG::UniqueViolation: DETAIL: Key (id)=(3068) already exists.
WARN -- Retrying creation: PG::UniqueViolation: DETAIL: Key (id)=(3069) already exists.
WARN -- Retrying creation: PG::UniqueViolation: DETAIL: Key (id)=(3070) already exists.
```

The IDs it's trying are in the 3000-4000 range, even though there are over 90000 records in the table in question.

Why is ActiveRecord or PostgreSQL wasting so much time sequentially trying existing IDs?

---

The original exception (simplified/removed query string):

```js
{
  "exception": "ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique",
  "message": "PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"table_name_pkey\"\nDETAIL:  Key (id)=(3023) already exists."
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure how it happened, but it turned out that the PostgreSQL sequence for the table's primary key was somehow reset or got out of sync with the table:

```sql
SELECT nextval('table_name_id_seq');
-- 3456

SELECT max(id) FROM table_name;
-- 95123
```

I had to restart the primary key sequence at the table's last ID:

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq RESTART 95124;
```

---

***Update:*** here's a Rake task to reset the ID sequence for most models on a Rails 4 with PostgreSQL project:

```
desc 'Resets Postgres auto-increment ID column sequences to fix duplicate ID errors'
task :reset_sequences => :environment do
  Rails.application.eager_load!

  ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each do |model|
    unless model.attribute_names.include?('id')
      Rails.logger.debug "Not resetting #{model}, which lacks an ID column"
      next
    end

    begin
      max_id = model.maximum(:id).to_i + 1
      result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
        "ALTER SEQUENCE #{model.table_name}_id_seq RESTART #{max_id};"
      )
      Rails.logger.info "Reset #{model} sequence to #{max_id}"
    rescue => e
      Rails.logger.error "Error resetting #{model} sequence: #{e.class.name}/#{e.message}"
    end
  end
end
```

---

The following references proved useful:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1427188
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10712838
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16533829

Comment: Any thoughts of how the IDs and sequence can get out of sync? This happened to me too, and the fix is easy, but I would like to know how the problem could have originally occurred...

Comment: In my case the sequences got out of sync due to a bulk data import that set IDs directly, but did not update the sequences.  *Maybe* it can also happen if concurrent processes are creating lots of records at the same time?

Answer (score 12):

You can also reset a sequence of a table 'table_name' using rails console

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('table_name')
```

(tested in rails 3.2, rails 5.0.1)